# How to exit GUARD outside and inside a function - Swift

Tags: swift, guard

In the following code I am practicing the use of GUARD (Book: OReilly Learning Swift)

```
guard 2+2 == 4 else {
print("The universe makes no sense")
return // this is mandatory!
}
print("We can continue with our daily lives")
```

Why do I get the following code error?

`error: return invalid outside of a func`

Or is GUARD only used within functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the condition in your `guard` statement is not met, the else branch has to exit the current scope. `return` can only be used inside functions, as the error message shows, but `return` is not the only way to exit scope.

You can use `throw` outside functions as well and if the `guard` statement is in a loop, you can also use `break` or `continue`.

`return` valid in functions:

```
func testGuard(){
    guard 2+2 == 4 else {
        print("The universe makes no sense")
        return // this is mandatory!
    }
    print("We can continue with our daily lives")
}
```

`throw` valid outside of function as well:

```
guard 2+2 == 4 else { throw NSError() }
```

`break` valid in loops:

```
for i in 1..<5 {
    guard i < 5 else {
        break
    }
}
```

`continue` valid in loops:

```
for someObject in someArray { 
    guard let someProperty = someObject.someOptionalProperty else { 
        continue 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for teaching!

Comment: you for got to add in `continue` as in `for someObject in someArray { guard let someProperty = someObject.someOptionalProperty else { continue } }`. I upvoted your  answer btw, it was very helpful for the `throw NSError()`

Answer (score 7):

> Or is GUARD only used within functions?

Not necessarily.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120):

> If that condition is not met, the code inside the `else` branch is executed. **That branch must transfer control to exit the code block in which the `guard` statement appears**. It can do this with a control transfer statement such as `return`, `break`, `continue`, or `throw`, or it can call a function or method that doesn’t return, such as `fatalError(_:file:line:)`.

For example this can be used in a Playgound on the top level

```
for i in 0...10 {
    guard i % 2 == 0 else { continue }
    print(i)
}
```

The error message is actually not related to `guard`. It just states that *`return`* cannot be used *outside of a func*

Comment: I appreciate your response, it helped me a lot for my learning, greetings!